# Trying to read a CSV file

Tags: r

i've converted a data frame into a csv file by using Rstudio and then i tried to read that csv file it is showing as :
cannot open file 'C:/Users/SRAVAN/OneDrive/Documents': Permission denied

please check it.

Comment: Do you have the file open when you try to import it?

Answer (score 0):

Although you haven't provided much info about your problem, RStudio comes with a simple file explorer. Just find your file in that explorer, click on it and choose `Import Dataset...`.

[image: RStudio file explorer]